# Making a Subscriber subscribe to a Subject in RxJava

Tags: rx-java, system.reactive

In RxJava 3, is there a way to subscribe a `Subscriber` to a `Subject`?
Subject is an `Observable` too which means it should be able to provide an upstream which others (`Subscriber` implementations like `DisposableSubscriber` or `DefaultSubscriber`) should be able to get data when Subject's `onNext` emits something. But below code gives compile-time error and I couldn't find any other mechanism to achieve that.

```
public class NewsPublisher {
    static Subject<Integer>  newsSubject = PublishSubject.create();

public class NewsSubscriber
    extends DisposableSubscriber<Integer> {

    void bind() {
        NewsPublisher.newsSubject.subscribe(this);
    }
```

Error message: Cannot resolve method 'subscribe(NewsSubscriber)'

Subject's `subscribe()` method only allows `Consumer` or `Observer` as an input. But logically speaking all I want is when Subject (being an Observable too) emits something, I can have a Subscriber listening and hence its `onNext()` be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

Decided to try the code by myself and found a kind of a workaround. Using lambda one can chain the onNext() method. The lambda istelf is an anonymus Consumer object, thus it may defeat the purpouse of the whole class (or not? depends on what else are you doing), but this works.

```
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.disposables.Disposable;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.subscribers.DisposableSubscriber;

public class NewsSubscriber extends DisposableSubscriber<Integer> {

    Disposable disposable;

    void bind() {
        disposable = NewsPublisher.newsSubject.subscribe(this::onNext);
    }

    public void onNext(Integer integer) {   
        // implement
    }

    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
        if (disposable != null) disposable.dispose();
    }

    public void onComplete() {
        disposable.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Martin, changing to `PublishSubject` didn't help. Error which is posted is complete i.e.; `Cannot resolve method 'subscribe(NewsSubscriber)'`. Message indicates that Subject's subscribe method does not accept `DisposableSubscriber` as input. Thats what my question is. How do we achieve that? thank you

Comment: Updated my answer.